# How to create custom drawn columns in or alongside tree view?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

A picture is worth 1000 words, so here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Desired Result]

In words, I would like to add a column to a tree view in which I can draw vertical connecting lines between certain rows of the tree view. This should work both when the tree view is scrolled, as well as when children of a row are expanded or collapsed.

First question: Is it at all feasible to do this within a `ttk.Treeview`? Since a tree view brings along all the additional functionality that I need, specifically for everything to the right of the connections column, I would prefer making use of it.

If not possible completely within a `ttk.Treeview`, how could I keep a separate canvas widget to the left of the tree view in sync with the tree view (row height, scroll position, collapsed/expanded children)?

Finally, if even keeping a canvas in sync with a tree view is not feasible, do you have an alternative suggestion regarding widgets and layouts in order to achieve this. Are there examples of using a grid layout to mimic the functionality of a tree view (expandable children, resizable columns)?

Comment: I remember doing something like this, but I drew the entire Treeview with a Canvas and emulated necessary behavior with events. I like your idea to us a grid but transparency seems to be an issue as long as you do not use canvas in those grid cells and put some sort of logical behavior in sync. Whats also possible, is insert pictures into the Treeview, it maybe worth a try, cause its much lesser math as for a drawn Treeview.